# Formula to sum a range of rows and copy the sums vertically downwards in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to display the sums of rows vertically using ctr+drag for over 80 rows downwards in one column to replicate the formula for the remaining 80 rows, but excel only continues to modify the formala if I drag horizontally.

Here is a small table to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

In cell A12 is the sum of rows A1:F1. I want to be able to display the sums of A2:F2 in cell A13, and A3:F3 in cell A14.

[image: Table]

At the moment I can only copy as value, and then transpose. But I don´t want to do this 80 times weekly when I receive this table.

Which formula would enable me to quickly calculate the sums of rows but display them vertically?

Comment: You can compute in columns, and transpose?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Could you show what your result is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to enter an [array formula](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Array-Formulas.html) for transposition. For this, select the destination column, e.g. `A14:A:19`, enter the `=TRANSPOSE(A12:F12)` command from the original row, and press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

What you want to achieve is thus easy in two steps: first sum into a new row `A12:F12`, then tranpose to a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in A12 to get the result:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&COLUMN()):INDIRECT("F"&COLUMN()))
```